# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

Its basically an android app and I am using godaddy server to store php files.

Android side :

I have two Fragment activities namely Feed and Profile.Both of these activities request some data from the server using a volley JSON request.Initially, both the activities load data properly using volley. However, after continuous switching between the activities Volley throws the following error.

I am getting the following Log error:

1-12 14:48:58.146 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)

The issue is from server side because I tried the same thing at 000webhost under free plan,it works great there.

Any help would be appreciated.thank you.

Comment: Are you using a singleton for the requestqueue?

Comment: Yes @samuel,I am using singleton for the requestqueue.

Comment: The default maximum number of parallel requests that could be going on at a time is 4. You could change that and see what happens

Comment: @SamuelDamilolaAgbede tried changing the value but its giving the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for replying late. I'm just seeing this. Have you gotten a solution now?

Comment: @Samuel  ya changing the request to GET did the trick.

Comment: same problem here but my request is already a GET

Answer (score 0):

for me , a VPNapp(hotspot shield) was open in my phone....after I stopped it ,I did not get this error